# Explain U-substititution with $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^{2x} +1}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

The [integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%28e%5E%7Bx%7D/%28e%5E%7B2x%7D%2b1%29,%20x,%200,%20%5Cinfty%29) does not diverge.

Choose $u = e^x$ so $\mathrm dx = \frac{\mathrm du}{e^x}$ so $\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+1})\mathrm dx$ becomes $\int_1^{\infty}( \frac{\mathrm du}{u^2 +1})$ but it [diverges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%281/%28u%5E%7B2%7D%2b1%29,%20x,%201,%20%5Cinfty%29).

What is the fallacy here? I clearly made some mistake in changing the base but I cannot spot it.

Comment: In your second link, you integrated with respect to $x$. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%281%2F%28u%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%29%2C+u%2C+1%2C+%5Cinfty%29) works fine.

Comment: By the way, it's the *integral* that doesn't diverge. There's no *equation* in sight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fallacy is the claim that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+1}$ diverges.

$$\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+1} &= \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t\frac{du}{u^2+1}\\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\arctan(u)\Bigm|_{1}^{t}\right)\\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\arctan(t) - \arctan(1)\right)\\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\arctan(t) - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*}$$

The second fallacy is believing that Wolframalpha is never wrong (even if you put in the wrong input).

Comment: I upvoted because of the last sentence... :D